# Build zeep in docker from alpine

Tags: python, linux, docker, dockerfile

First things first:  I struggled a little building the zeep pacakge in a docker alpine image, but I finally got it working.  I hope that this post can help others with zeep on alpine in docker.

The question:  After I got the zeep build to work, I had the simple issue of copying my build results to the new image.  I used `tar` and `COPY FROM` eventually, but I was wondering if there is a better way of getting my build results from my build image to my deployment image.  It is not clear to me that I got all the dependencies, but the module loads successfully.

Ultimately, here's the Dockerfile that I settled on:

```
FROM alpine AS build-stage
RUN apk add python3-dev build-base libxml2-dev libxslt-dev 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN  pip3 install zeep 
RUN cd /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ && tar zcf /packages.tgz *

FROM alpine AS deploy-stage
RUN apk add python3  libxml2 libxslt 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY --from=build-stage /packages.tgz  /
RUN cd /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ && tar zxf /packages.tgz  && rm /packages.tgz
```

The next portion of this question is to express some of the difficulty I had with getting zeep to build.  I'm not asking for analysis here but rather I'm including these error messages to make this post more searchable for others having similar problems (in other words, stop reading here).

I used `FROM centos` to build a python docker image that used zeep (for SOAP).  However, to shrink the image size (it was a 1G image), I wanted to use `FROM alpine`.  Once I made the move to alpine, the `pip-3 install zeep` fails.

/bin/sh: pip-3: not found

Well, python3 on alpine calls pip `pip3`.

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/etree.o -w
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
creating tmp
cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitg55bfhan.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitg55bfhan.o
unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cq2qcz1c/lxml/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cq2qcz1c/lxml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
install --record /tmp/pip-record-nmuulbim/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Apparently, the install of the zeep package needs to compile "something".  As I understand it, docker will allow me to build stuff in one image and copy it to another image.  This allows me to install the compiler, build zeep, and then copy the end results to my new image, throwing away all the tools I used to build it.

To correct the need for the compiler, I added the line `RUN apk add build-base` to my Dockerfile.

I next hit this error:

```
 #include "libxml/xpath.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
```

Let me try to add the libxml2 lib.  I added this line `RUN apk add libxml2` and got this result:

```
ERROR: b'/bin/sh: xslt-config: not found\n'
** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
```

However, that line is way up in the error results (and easy to miss).  So, following that suggestion, I replaced the last `add libxml2` with `RUN apk add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`.   Now that I had the development versions of those libraries installed, I hit this error:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/etree.o -w
src/lxml/etree.c:97:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include "Python.h"
```

It looks like I have to include the header files for python, too.  I modified my `apk add` command to look like this:  `RUN apk add python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`.  Now, putting it altogether (and combining `apk add` commands), I have this to build zeep.  At this point, this is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine AS build-stage
RUN apk add python3-dev build-base libxml2-dev libxslt-dev 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN  pip3 install zeep
```

This builds an image that I can use to import zeep:

```
$ docker run -it f1ac77dacbda sh
/ # python3 
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:25:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zeep
>>>
```

So that looks good.  And the really good news is that my image size is 312 MB, down from 1.05 GB (my original centos image).   Now, that I've built zeep, I want to discard all of the larger devel packages and just stick with the runtimes.  I also need to grab my zeep package (and it's dependencies) and add them to my deployment image.

To be honest, I don't know how to accurately determine the zeep dependencies without spending a lot of time.  So, I just wanted to copy zeep from the packages directory.  I discovered my package location this way:

```
$ docker run -it 2b53acb67b25 sh
/ # python3 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/',
    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

To copy my build results, I tried this command:

```
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/ /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/
```

This copied my zeep package over, but not its dependency packages:

```
$ docker run -it 1292276a94da  sh
/ # python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:25:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zeep
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zeep.client import CachingClient, Client  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/client.py", line 4, in <module>
    from zeep.settings import Settings
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/settings.py", line 4, in <module>
    import attr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attr'
```

This is now my question (repeated from the initial summary)- how do I accurately copy it's dependencies from my build-stage to the deploy stage?

While I could add a `COPY FROM` for the `attr` package and each package I subsequently discover to be missing, I opted to brute force copy them all.  The `COPY` command doesn't appear to have any recursive abilities and the directory structures are not maintained.  So, I opted to put everything into a tar ball and copy that over.  So here's my final Dockerfile for building and deploying zeep:

```
FROM alpine AS build-stage
RUN apk add python3-dev build-base libxml2-dev libxslt-dev 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN  pip3 install zeep 
RUN cd /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ && tar zcf /packages.tgz *

FROM alpine AS deploy-stage
RUN apk add python3  libxml2 libxslt 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY --from=build-stage /packages.tgz  /
RUN cd /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ && tar zxf /packages.tgz  && rm /packages.tgz
```

Is there a more accurate way of copying the build results over, capturing all the dependencies, and excluding unnecessary packages (perhaps there were some packages that got downloaded for build only).